# sending email from g-mail host to five different email accounts using c#

Tags: c#, email

I want to sent email to 5 different email accounts, my problem is in the following code whenever I active those line of code which has "**----> this line**" it works fine but when I deactivate those line it sends out five email to one email account and nothing to others.

does any one know what is wrong with my code ?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread t = null;
        MailMessage mailMessage;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //textBox1 is recipients email addresses 
            String[] to = textBox1.Text.Split(';');

            foreach (String s in to)
            {
                Object[] array = new Object[2];
                array[0] = (textBox4.Text.ToString());
                array[1] = (s.ToString());
               // MessageBox.Show(s.ToString()); -----> this line 
                t = new Thread(sentEmail);
                t.Start(array);
                //MessageBox.Show("from: " + array[0].ToString()); -----> this line 
               // MessageBox.Show("to: " + array[1].ToString()); ----->this line 
                Thread.Sleep(50);


            }       

        }


        void sentEmail(Object array)
        {
            Object[] o = array as Object[];
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);
            mailMessage = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(o[0].ToString()), new MailAddress(o[1].ToString()));
            mailMessage.Body = textBox3.Text;
            mailMessage.Subject = textBox2.Text;
            client.Send(mailMessage);


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: This is clearly an issue with how you're sending out the mails and not with those lines.

Comment: what is the issue ? could you give me some hint please ?

Comment: The issue is clearly stated: "it sends out five email to one email account and nothing to others"

Answer (score 2):

You're storing the `mailMessage` as a property of the Form, and the address is getting changed by another thread before it's actually sent.  Adding the `MessageBox` lets one thread finish befiore another one starts.  Just change `sentMail` to create a new `MailMessage` instead of reusing the existing one and you should be fine:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t = null;
    //MailMessage mailMessage;  <-- take out this line

    void sentEmail(Object array)
    {
        Object[] o = array as Object[];
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text);
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(o[0].ToString()), new MailAddress(o[1].ToString()));  // <-- don't use the Form property
        mailMessage.Body = textBox3.Text;
        mailMessage.Subject = textBox2.Text;
        client.Send(mailMessage);


    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot . It solved the problem . but now it sends emails at the same time while I define Thread.Sleep(2000); I need that it sends email to each email account with a delay . when I checked my different email accounts I saw all of them are sent at the same time . while it was not an issue when I used the old code with those line acctivated. any idea why?

Comment: Well that's only a 2-second delay, so it may not be noticeable.  That may be a function of the SMTP and/or POP server you're using - the SMTP server may not send mail at the exact time it receives the SMTP data.  Email is not designed to be instantaneous.

Comment: I test longer Tread.Sleep(5000); but result is the same as before. Do you know any other function of the SMPT or POP server that can solve it? thanks

Comment: No, I don't.  POP is designed to retrieve email in batches, not real-time.  Why do you need a delay?  If they're going to 5 different people why can't they be delivered at the same time.

Comment: My client asked me to design the app like that.So it needs to be done exactly the way he wants

Comment: Does your client understand that you have no control over when gmail processes SMTP requests or when POP clients download their mail?  If you can prove that _your_ program delays for 2 seconds each time I don't know what else you can do.  Plus, if you need a 2-second delay then why are you doing it asynchronously?  sending an email should take much less than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the `mailMessage` object. I suspect the lines you have commented out slow the processing down enough that the 5 distinct messages are sent correctly / the thread complete. When they are not there you are getting the weird behaviour as the threads are accessing the same object.

Was going to clean up the code here, but @D_Stanley has you covered.

Comment: To add to @Matthew's response, just make `mailMessage` a local variable in the function. Why is it a class variable, anyway?